# Silverstripe - installation files explained

Tags: installation, silverstripe

in a fresh silverstripe installation (3.0.5) there are many files where I wonder if I will ever need them or what their purpose is... so what I would like to have is a clean silverstripe installation and delete all unnecessary files/folders.

For what do I need these files/folders?:

```
phpunit.teamcity.mssql.xml
phpunit.teamcity.postgresql.xml
phpunit.teamcity.sqlite3.xml
phpunit.teamcity.xml
phpunit.xml.dist
test.php
web.config
vendor
```

many thanks for the clarification.
Florian

Comment: short answer: all of these are safe to delete for production environments as they contain general information or configuration for unit testing; exception is 'web.config' which might be neccessary when using IIS instead of apache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHPUNIT / TeamCity**

```
phpunit.teamcity.mssql.xml
phpunit.teamcity.postgresql.xml
phpunit.teamcity.sqlite3.xml
phpunit.teamcity.xml
phpunit.xml.dist
```

those are files used to configure php unit and team city (team city is a continuous integration software by jetbrains https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)
(if you don't use teamcity, you can safely delete this files)

**Web Server Config**

```
.htaccess
```

this is the configuration file for apache web servers (if you don't use apache, you can delete this file)

```
web.config
```

this is for Microsoft IIS web servers, it is the equivalent to the .htaccess (if you don't use IIS as web server you can delete this file)

**GIT (Version Control System)**

```
.git/
.gitignore
.gitatributes
```

if you don't use git, you don't need them

**Composer**

```
    composer.json
    vendor/
```

the composer file holds information of php dependencies and where to get them.
the vendor folder is the folder where composer installs its dependencies
(composer is a php dependency manager which I can really recommend http://getcomposer.org/)
(if you do not use composer, you don't need them)

**PHP files**

```
index.php
```

fallback file in case mod_rewrite or the ISS equivalent is not working

```
install.php
```

the installer for SilverStripe, **this file should be deleted after you installed SilverStripe**

```
install-frameworkmissing.html
```

part of the installer

**behat**

```
behat.yml
```

I can't say much about behat because I don't use it, here is a quote from the website (http://behat.org/): *"A php framework for testing your business expectations."*
All I can say is that you can delete the file if you don't use behat

**Other**

```
test.php
```

no idea, I have never seen this file

README.md
obviously the readme file

```
CONTRIBUTING.md
```

a info file containing information on guidelines for contributing back to SilverStripe

```
Makefile
build.xml
```

Can't exactly say how to use those 2 files, but unless you do use them, you can delete them safely

---

**tl;dr**

the only files you really need is one of those 2:

- if you are using apache (linux and mac but also windows) then you need to keep .htaccess
- if you are IIS (windows server) then you need web.config

and the index.php if mod_rewrite is not available on your server

all other files are just for 3rd party software the core developers use